# Suggested gitlab configuration directory permissions?

Tags: git, configuration, permissions, gitlab

I just installed Gitlab community edition on Archlinux and I would like people use `git` user to push changes. To do so, I set `user: git` in `/etc/webapps/gitlab/gitlab.yml`.

Now I added a test ssh key through the web interface but I can't see it into `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`. I [found](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/49206) that `gitlab:check` could rebuild the keys index, so I ran

```
sudo su - git -s /bin/sh -c "cd '/usr/share/webapps/gitlab'; bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

but the command ended with:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /usr/share/webapps/gitlab/config/application
/usr/share/webapps/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/usr/share/webapps/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/webapps/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Apparently this is a [permission](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/49206) problem related to the `/etc/webapps/gitlab` directory, which is owned by `gitlab:gitlab` and has permission `750`.
If I add git user to gitlab group I get further down in the execution but it fails because of a permission denied in the same directory.

So, *what permissions are adviced on `/etc/webapps/gitlab`?*

In general, if I choose to have `git` as the *front-end* account (meaning I want users to push `git@my.domain`) do I need some special configuration?

I thought `git` was the *public* user and `gitlab` the administrative one (meaning with that gitlab services run under such user).